# C# WPF Update label on window from 2nd cs code file

Tags: c#, wpf

Newbie here so sorry for the dumb question but I'm having a real problem with this simple little issue for some reason.  I have a label and text block on a WPF window and I'm trying to update those from a 2nd cs code file. I've tried the below code but the label is not getting updated...any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

- 820File.cs

  ```
  MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
  string status820Text = "Now importing blah";
  string status820Label = "Now importing blah";
  main.Update820Status(ref status820Text, ref status820Label);
  ```
- MainWindow.cs

  ```
  public void Update820Status(ref string status820Text, ref string status820Label)
  {
      this.StatusLabel.Content =status820Label;
      this.StatusTextBlock.Text = status820Text;
  }
  ```

...and it runs but the Label and TextBlock are not getting updated or rather not displaying the text passed through.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks pretty much ok, the problem could be elsewhere. Can you show how you create your Label and TextBlock?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `ref` parameters.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `main = new MainWindow()`, you're creating a brand-new `MainWindow` instance that has nothing to do with the existing window on the screen.

You need to pass the existing `MainWindow` instance.

Comment: SLaks is right. In some situations like yours you could also try using `Application.Current.MainWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

That would work in WinForms - not in WPF-window.

Try to add a parameter instead. And then read it after the new window is closed (or add a eventhandler to update immediately).

820File.cs

```
MyWindow w = new MyWindow();
w.MyProperty = "Now importing blah"; // Here we set the initial text
w.ShowDialog(); // Show a modal dialog so this class waits for the changed text
string changedText = w.MyProperty; // Here we read the changed text
```

MyWindow

```
public partial class Mywindow : Window
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public MyWindow()
    {
    }
    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyProperty = "Some new text"; // Set the text to something new
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrong.  It will fail in both WinForms and WPF, because he's using the wrong instance.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works in WPF

axml in your window:

```
 <Label x:Name="lblStatus" Foreground="Red" Content=""/>
```

code behind in your page:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Label lbl = (Label)Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("lblStatus");
   lbl.Content = "New text";
}
```